# How to write multiple sheets in Excel using TSMExportToXls Delphi component

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, export-to-excel, delphi-6

I am using [TSMExportToXls](http://www.scalabium.com/sme/sme_faq.htm#Q1) component for writing Excel files from data set. I am facing difficulty in writing different sheets in Excel files. It works file for single sheet. I don't know how to write in multiple sheets.
Below is my code. Any help would be appreciated.

```
procedure TfrmXLSExport.btnExportClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  SMExportToXLS1.Header.Add('New Sheet Data');
  SMExportToXLS1.Execute;
end;
```

I've created `TTable` object, populated the data in it and set it as a DataSet property of `TSMExportToXls`

Comment: Does the component come with any documentation or sample code?

Comment: Yes, it comes with documentation and have sample codes, but  I've not found any demo code to create Excel file with multiple sheet using the mentioned component. Thanks.

Comment: @HeartWare. I appreciate your effort but its TSMExportToXls component not TMSExportToXls, thanks :)

Comment: The document says the following line 
"This component is not use the MS Excel application as OLE-server and very quick but this component is not supports of font/color exporting - you can export a data only (with alignments and column width)."

Comment: Really? I noticed that you had changed it to TMS in the body on an edit 6 hours ago (from now), but not in the subject, so I changed it in the subject. Now you have changed it back in the body, but forgotten the subject :-).

Comment: Have you asked the vendor yet? I'm sure they know the answer.

Answer (score 0):

In SMExport you may use the TSMExportToExcel component to create the multisheet workbook.
You may check the sample project in DEMOS\Merge\XLS directory

Comment: Thanks @Mike, but I don't want to use the Excel Ole. TSMExportToExcel make use of Excel Ole.

Comment: And what's this 255 character limit that TSMExportToXls have ?. Does it means that I cannot write more than 255 character in an Excel cell. ?

Answer (score 0):

As alternative, you may use the TSMExportToXLSX component to generate the xlsx-files.
But TSMExportToXLS do not support the merge feature.

Answer (score 0):

I use this code (Delphi):

```
procedure TFormMain.ExportExec(aDataSet: TDataSet; aSheetName: string);
var FirstTime : integer;
begin
  Inc(FirstTime);
  //use this code to delete default worksheets but only the first time instead 
  //it will delete those newly created
  if FirstTime = 1 then
    XLS.DeleteDefaultSheets := True
  else
    XLS.DeleteDefaultSheets := False;

  XLS.DataSet := aDataSet;
  XLS.KeyGenerator := aSheetName;
  XLS.Execute;
end;
```

And this is how I setted up the TSMExportToExcel component.
[image]

Hope this help! :D